# Can I inherit background-color from hovered item?

Tags: html, css

Html

```
<ul>
    <li class="first active">Test</li>
    <li class="second">Test</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul li {
    padding: 10px
}

.first:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.second:hover {
    background-color: grey;
}

.active {

}
```

I want to display .active item with same state as :hover. My point here to inherit li colour for active items.

Is this any way to do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/o3c6js03/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking is not possible; the `inherit` value sets a property to be the same as the corresponding property of the parent element.

If you're writing out individual styles for the `:hover` state of each `li` anyway, then simply add the `.active` class to the same rule - CSS rules can have multiple selectors, you just need to separate them with commas.

For example:

```
ul li{
    padding:10px
}
.first:hover,.first.active{
    background-color:red;
}
.second:hover,.second.active{
    background-color:grey;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was so easy :)

Comment: You're welcome. If this answers your question to your satisfaction, don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: I don't forgot :) SO didn't allow me to mark comment as solution in first 10 minutes

Comment: Yup, spotted the question was only 8 mins old after I posted that comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to achieve this:

```
.first:hover,
.first.active {
    background-color: red;
}

.second:hover,
.second.active {
    background-color: grey;
}
```